# Search filter in custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, search

I'm trying to create a filter search (using EditText) to search through my custom ListView items. I've tried to do it but it seems, that there is something wrong, because when i try to search (type in EditText) nothing happens.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance! :)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
private ListView mListView;
private AnimalAdapter mAdapter;
ProgressBar mProgressBar;
EditText mEditText;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, "code", "code");
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Animal.class);
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    header.setPadding(2, 8, 4, 2);



    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.animal_list);
    mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mListView.addHeaderView(header);


    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById (R.id.loading_animals);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);





    RemoteDataTask task = new RemoteDataTask();
    task.execute();



    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_animal);
      mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                System.out.println("Text ["+s+"] - Start ["+start+"] - Before ["+before+"] - Count ["+count+"]");
              if (count < before) {
                      // We're deleting char so we need to reset the adapter data
                      mAdapter.resetData();
              }

              mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

            }});
}








 public void updateData(){


     ParseQuery<Animal> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Animal.class);
  query.setCachePolicy(CachePolicy.CACHE_THEN_NETWORK);
query.orderByAscending("animal");
  query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Animal>() {

      @Override
      public void done(List<Animal> animals, ParseException error) {

          if(animals != null){
              mAdapter.clear();
           mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          for (int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++) {

                  mAdapter.add(animals.get(i));

              }


          }



      }
  });
}


 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                refreshIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                refreshIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                startActivity(refreshIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                     return true; 
             } 
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }



     private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {




         @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog





            }


         @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                updateData();


                return null;
            }


         @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

             mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.animal_list);
                // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
             mAdapter = new AnimalAdapter(MainActivity.this, new ArrayList<Animal>());


                mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);





                } 

            }


     }
```

AnimalAdapter.java

```
public class AnimalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Animal> implements Filterable{
private Context mContext;
private List<Animal> mAnimals;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
ArrayAdapter<Animal> array;
DisplayImageOptions options;
Activity activity;
private Filter animalFilter;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public AnimalAdapter(Context context, List<Animal> objects) {
      super(context, R.layout.animal_row_item, objects);


      ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).build();

      imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheInMemory()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .build();

        this.mContext = context;
        this.mAnimals = objects;
  }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
      if(convertView == null){
          LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
          convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.animal_row_item, null);
      }


      final Animal animal = mAnimals.get(position);


      TextView animalView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.animal_text);
      TextView areaView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.area_text);

      final ImageView animalPic = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.animal_pic);
      final ProgressBar indicator = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

      indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      animalPic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //Setup a listener we can use to switch from the loading indicator to the Image once it's ready
        ImageLoadingListener listener = new ImageLoadingListener(){



            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {
                indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                animalPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View view, FailReason arg2) {


            }

        };

      imageLoader.displayImage(getItem(position).getImgUrl(), animalPic,options, listener);
      animalView.setText(animal.getAnimal());
      areaView.setText(animal.getArea());


      convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MoreActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("about", animal.getAbout());
                intent.putExtra("animal", animal.getAnimal());
                intent.putExtra("imgUrl", animal.getImgUrl());
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
      });

      return convertView;
  }


 public void resetData() {
     mAnimals = mAnimals;
```

}

```
 @Override
 public Filter getFilter() {
         if (animalFilter == null) 
               animalFilter = new AnimalFilter();

         return animalFilter;
 }
```

private class AnimalFilter extends Filter {

```
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // We implement here the filter logic
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    // No filter implemented we return all the list
                    results.values = mAnimals;
                    results.count = mAnimals.size();
            }
            else {
                    // We perform filtering operation
                    List<Animal> nPlanetList = new ArrayList<Animal>();

                    for (Animal a : mAnimals) {
                            if (a.getAnimal().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                                    nPlanetList.add(a);
                    }

                    results.values = mAnimals;
                    results.count = mAnimals.size();

            }
            return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {

            // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
            if (results.count == 0)
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else {
                    mAnimals = (List<Animal>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

    }
```

} 
}

Animal.java

```
@ParseClassName("Animal")
```

public class Animal extends ParseObject{

```
public Animal(){

  }

  public String getAnimal(){
      return getString("animal");
  }

  public void setAnimal(String animal){
      put("animal", animal);
  }

  public String getArea(){
      return getString("area");
  }

  public void setArea(String area){
      put("area", area);
  }

  public String getImgUrl(){
      return getString("imgUrl");
  }

  public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl){
      put("imgUrl", imgUrl);
  }

  public String getAbout(){
      return getString("about");
  }

  public void setAbout(String about){
      put("about", about);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Just add `mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);`